# Android HCE response 6A82

Tags: android, apdu, hce

Im currently working on a HCE implementation for my Galaxy s4. I have a Omnikey 5321-cl reader which supportes 7816-4. My android class looks like this:

```
public class NfcHceService extends HostApduService{
private int counter         = 0;

@Override
public void onStart(android.content.Intent intent, int startId)
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Log.d("HCE", String.valueOf(counter));
                counter++;
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).run();
}

@Override
public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] apdu, Bundle extras)
{
    byte[] response = null;
    if (apdu[2] == 0xA4)
    {
        // return selecting applet
        response = new byte[] { (byte) 0x90, 0x00 };

    }
    return response;
}

@Override
public void onDeactivated(int reason)
{
    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
    Log.d("HCE", "onDeactivated");

}
```

}

And my reader class looks like this:

```
private static final byte[] CLA_INS_P1_P2   = { 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00 };
private static final byte[] AID_ANDROID     = { (byte) 0xF0, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06 };

private static byte[] createSelectAidApdu(byte[] aid)
{
    byte[] result = new byte[6 + aid.length];
    System.arraycopy(CLA_INS_P1_P2, 0, result, 0, CLA_INS_P1_P2.length);
    result[4] = (byte) (aid.length);
    System.arraycopy(aid, 0, result, 5, aid.length);
    result[result.length - 1] = 10;
    return result;
}

public static void Create_MF() throws CardException
{

    // --Variable declaration
    Card card = null;
    ResponseAPDU answer = null;
    // ---------------------------------------------

    // --1--Establish connection with the smart card
    TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
    List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();
    // Use the first terminal
    CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(1);
    // Connect with the card
    card = terminal.connect("*");
    CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();
    // ---------------------------------------------

    byte[] selectAidApdu = createSelectAidApdu(AID_ANDROID);

    answer = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(selectAidApdu));
```

My AID for the hce service is F0010203040506.

My Problem now is that I get a correct Select APDU on my android device which looks like this:

```
> RX: Type 4 Tag Command (13 bytes)
  CLA:0x00
  INS:0xA4(Select)
  P1:0x04(Name)
  P2:0x00(First or Only)
  LC:0x07(7)
  Data(7 bytes)
   00: f0 01 02 03 04 05 06
  Le:0x0A(10)
```

But I get a response code 6A82. As I understand it, this means that the device doesn t find the service. But I dont understand why.
Can anybody help?

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hce"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc.hce" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <service
        android:name=".NfcHceService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
            android:resource="@xml/hce_service" />
    </service>
</application>
```

And the xml file:

```
<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:description="@string/my_app_hce_service" >
<aid-group
    android:category="other"
    android:description="@string/my_app_aid_group" >
    <aid-filter android:name="F0010203040506" />
</aid-group></host-apdu-service>
```

**Update**

```
public static void Create_MF() throws CardException
{

    // --Variable declaration
    Card card = null;
    ResponseAPDU answer = null;
    // ---------------------------------------------

    // --1--Establish connection with the smart card
    TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
    List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();
    // Use the first terminal
    CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(1);
    // Connect with the card
    card = terminal.connect("*");
    CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();
    // ---------------------------------------------

    byte[] selectAidApdu = { 0x00, (byte) 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, 0x07, (byte) 0xF0, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06 }; // createSelectAidApdu(AID_ANDROID);

    answer = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(selectAidApdu));}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I tried to implement the isDefaultServiceForAid(). But Im not sure if Im using it correctly and if it does what I want.

```
    CardEmulation card = CardEmulation.getInstance(NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this));
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), NfcHceService.class);
    boolean tmp = card.isDefaultServiceForAid(comp, "F0010203040506");
```

Does it really test the AID of my service or does it something else? I want to test if my service is accessable with the AID I specified in my hce_service.xml which is declared in my Manifest.

Comment: The code snippets in your question do not match the sample code that you provided in the comments to the answer below. Please update the question to match the actual code that you tried!

Comment: The shared projekt is my last version and its not very different. The basic idea stayed the same I just tried a few thing since my original post

Comment: APDU processing in that sample project and in the above question is very different!

Comment: Well thats true but since I cant access the processapdu method. That was not realy part of the question.

Comment: So you do *not* receive the SELECT APDU on the phone? (As opposed to what you wrote in your question...)

Comment: I receive the correct apdu but i still get the 6a82 response and the processapdu method would return 9000

Comment: So the processCommandApdu method on the phone **is** called. It therefore **does** matter what you actually do in that method. Hence: Post the code that you actually use!

Comment: I have updated the Service class. The thread is just for test purposes because I wanted to make sure that my service is running when I send a apdu command. And for clarification: My processApdu method is never called!!! But I dont understand why. I always get an APDU command 6a82 which means that the command didnt find the selected service.

Comment: So we are running in circles here: How did you find out that you receive the SELECT APDU on the phone if processCommandApdu is *not* called?

Comment: Because I of the LogCat. If you look at my original post I get a LogCat entry which looks like this: RX: Type 4 Tag Command (13 bytes)
  CLA:0x00
  INS:0xA4(Select)
  P1:0x04(Name)
  P2:0x00(First or Only)
  LC:0x07(7)
  Data(7 bytes)
   00: f0 01 02 03 04 05 06
  Le:0x0A(10). But I only receive 6a82 response which indicates that the service was not found.

Comment: And you have made sure that `processCommandApdu` is never called by adding a line like `Log.d("HCE", "processCommandApdu");` as the first line of code of that method?

Comment: Yes. But i don t undetstand why the method is not called. As i understand hce, android just needs a apdu select command with an api and i get the correct apdu in my logcat but the method is stilll not called

Comment: Is there anything else in the log that might be relevant to HCE? Other than `if (apdu[2] == 0xA4)` which should be `if (apdu[1] == (byte)0xA4)` (note both the wrong index and the wrong integer comparison) and that you return `null` instead of a status word in other cases (which you should not) I don't see anything wrong with your code (though that dooes not change anything if `processCommandApdu` is not called anyways.

Comment: Thats right but I just dont know how to proceed. I tried a different reader, 50 diff. AIDs but its still the same. And I don t have another 4.4 phone so I cant test, if its a hardware problem.

Comment: I finally got it to work. I dont have a clue why it didnt work before but yesterday I restartet the whole process and it worked perfekt on my first try.

Answer (score 1):

The error `6A82` means `file not found`.

In this case it means that the AID you are selecting does not exist.

This is probably due to a mismatch between the AID you are selecting e.g. `f0 01 02 03 04 05 06` and the AID specified in your AndroidManifest.xml

ISO 7816 Reference [here](http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_5_basic_organizations.aspx#table18)

**Update:**

From inspecting your updated code it looks like you are adding another byte to the end of the APDU i.e. `0x10`. Try removing the following line from the function `createSelectAidApdu()`

```
result[result.length - 1] = 10;
```

Also, i'm not sure why you set the last byte to be 10, which is equals 16 in decimal. Note that the last byte is often used to specify the amount of data expected/requested from the target device. It is not always required, which is the case for the select application command.

Comment: Thats one of the first things I checked but thats not the case. Updated version above

Comment: Thats just the lenth of the response message and I already tried to leave it out. But a8 got the same 6a82 response

Comment: Ok, try this byte array declaration instead:
byte[] result = new byte[4 + aid.length];

Comment: I tried to use a custom byte array which contains the necessary values but I still get a 6A82 response code. For the APDU command the byte array has to be (5 + AID.length) long. Cause APDU = CLA,INS,P1,P2,AID.length,AID. I can only leave the response msg length out. Any ideas?

Comment: Please note that AID.length needs to be in HEX format. Try converting the entire byte array to a hex string and inspect in the debugger. Ensure the length is correct. Have you tried uninstalling the app from phone and re-installing, clear data etc. Also, when you call  card = terminal.connect("*"); Are you sure you are getting a connection to the card. Can you get the ATS from the HCE device?

Comment: Yes I get a connection to my android device and I get the APDU command I specified (in hex form). But somehow I cant access my custom service and I dont understand why not.

Comment: Does your xml file begin with <aid-group>??? It should also have <host-apdu-service .... >

Comment: But I dont know whats the problem. I create an APDU command on the reader and my android device gets the same APDU command but somehow the android os doesnt identifies my service as the one called and because of that I get the 6A82 response. At least thats what I think

Comment: Ok, feel free to share the project with me and I will try and help you.

Comment: I wasnt sure how to share it. I put it into a dropbox link. Hope this works.   https://www.dropbox.com/s/0rr8rejwnbr2bm7/Projekt.rar

Answer (score 0):

I think the AID selection goes allright. If Android does not have an app for the AID, it does nothing, not even transceive an error code.

I suspect the problem is that the app returns null as message, and thus Android probably sends an error code back.

The following if-statement tests negative as apdu[2] is actually (byte) 0x04. apdu[1] would be (byte) 0xA4.

```
byte[] response = null;
if (apdu[2] == 0xA4)
{
    // return selecting applet
    response = new byte[] { (byte) 0x90, 0x00 };

}
return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just been playing with a similar thing.

I notice that your intent-filter specifies an action of "android.nfc.cardemulation.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" but the correct action seems to be "android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" - see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html for details.

Using this action in the intent-filter, I successfully got my Android service being invoked for my AID.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem - my AID was correct on both ends, yet the service could still not be found.

The [official HCE page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html) has the following snippet:

```
<service android:name=".MyHostApduService" android:exported="true"
     android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE"/>
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
           android:resource="@xml/apduservice"/>
```

I noticed that the `<intent-filter>` did not have a `<category>` tag. I added this, and suddenly my service could be found! See below:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" />
    <!-- category required!!! this was not included in official android HCE documentation -->
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```